# Trying to connect to SQL Server database using TestComplete 11, but I am getting an error

Tags: sql-server, odbc, testcomplete

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server database using TestComplete 11, but I am getting an error

> Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.

I have added the ODBC Driver, you can look at the screenshot

[image: ODBC Data Source Administrator]

Below is the code I am using, please let me know how can I fix it.

```js
AConnection = ADO.CreateADOConnection();

// Specify the connection string
var AConnection = ADO.CreateADOConnection();

AConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLDriver; Server = KEOUS-SQL\MSSQLSERVER01,1724; Database=K212.HrPayroll.ThamesValley.Hina;user id = sql.server;password=sql.server";

// Suppress the login dialog box    
AConnection.LoginPrompt = false;    
AConnection.Open();

// Execute a simple query    
RecSet = AConnection.Execute_("SELECT * FROM EC_GROUP WHERE EMP_GROUP_CODE = 'ADMIN1'");

// Iterate through query results and insert data into the test log    
RecSet.MoveFirst();

while(! RecSet.EOF)    
{    
    Log.Message(RecSet.Fields.Item("EC_GROUP").Value, RecSet.Fields.Item("EMP_GROUP_CODE").Value);    
    RecSet.MoveNext();
}    
AConnection.Close();
```

Comment: You should edit your question to display code correctly, and also tag the question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As TestComplete is a 32 bit application, it will only work with strictly 32 bit ODBC drivers. Use a data source  that is configured with a 32 bit driver.

Comment: @inquisitive_mind This sounds like something that is the shape of an answer (at least it's not obvious to me it's not an answer). Would you mind clarifying why you checked that review option?

Comment: @badcook You are right, It does look like an answer.My bad I've deleted the comment.